# Problems with keyboard functions?

Tags: function, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, ibaction

I am having some trouble with the return key on the keyboard executing code. I have tried in the past and the following code worked perfectly fine:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    valueOfLetter()
    return true;
}
```

But, for some reason, there is an error on the line `valueOfLetter`.

Here is the entire file in case it is necessary:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBOutlet weak var strWordValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var strInputField: UITextField!


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    valueOfLetter()
    return true;
}

 var TextField: UITextField!

    func valueOfLetter(inputLetter: String) -> Int {
        let alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

        for (index, letter) in alphabet {
            if letter = inputLetter.lowercaseString {
                return index + 1

                for character in word {
                    score += valueOfLetter(character)
                }
            }
        }

        return 0
    }
}
```

The error is: "missing argument in parameter #1 in call

The is another error on the line `for (index, letter) in alphabet` which says: 'String' not convertible to '([String, String])'

I am unsure of what these errors mean or how to fix them.

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is because your `[String]` array cannot be fast-enumerated as a pair of indices and values. To do so, you need to use the `enumerate` function like mentioned above.

I would recommend promoting your `alphabet` array to a global or member variable. You can mark it as private so that it is not visible outside that source file.

```
// A through Z
private let alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

You can use two functions to compute the score for a word. The first function will calculate the number of points for a specific letter. The second function will take a string and enumerate through it, summing up the point values for each letter.

```
func valueOfLetter(letter: Character) -> Int
{
    let letterString = String(letter).uppercaseString
    let index = find(alphabet, letterString)

    return index != nil ? index! + 1 : 0
}

func scoreForWord(word: String) -> Int
{
    let characters = Array(word)
    return characters.reduce(0) { sum, letter in sum + valueOfLetter(letter) }
}
```

I know this is a bit different than your initial setup. I just wanted to point out how useful the [built-in Swift library functions are](http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/14/the-swift-standard-library-list-of-built-in-functions/). Namely `filter`, `map`, and `reduce`.

EDIT: Here is how you can use each method via `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
// This will be called every time the text changes in the UITextField
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let currentWord = textField.text as NSString
    let newWord = currentWord.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    let score = scoreForWord(newWord)

    // Do something with the score here

    return true
}

// This will be called when the return key is pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    let word = textField.text
    let score = scoreForWord(word)

    // Do something with the score here

    return true
}
```

Comment: These functions are part of your `ViewController`, you can call them when you need via `UITextFieldDelegate`, depending on your implementation.
  
For example, if you wanted to display the score in real-time (as user types), you could use the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` delegate method. If you wanted it on return key, `textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method.

I'll update the post to reflect either.

Comment: This completely fixed my problem.

Answer (score 8):

Your method `valueOfLetter` takes a parameter, you need to call it with a parameter or it won't work. For instance:

```
 valueOfLetter("x")
```

Your second error is occurring because you're using a syntactic structure used to iterate over a dictionary with an array. Use the built-in `enumerate` function to iterate over an array with index values:

```
   for (index, letter) in enumerate(alphabet) {
        if letter = inputLetter.lowercaseString {
            return index + 1

            for character in word {
                score += valueOfLetter(character)
            }
        }
    }
```